# Sort Rows by number

Tags: java

there is a class hierarchy, a Table class and a Rows class, the table consists of rows, I would like to sort the rows in the array I selected by the row number, please tell me how to do this. In the handler class, I can create a table and rows, and the row has fields: row number and row content, the table has a field: table number

```
public class Rows {
private int number; 
private String data; 
private int numT;
public void setNumber(int number) { this.number = number;}
public void setData(String data) { this.data = data; }
public int getNumber() { return number; }
public String getData() { return data; }
public Rows() {
    number = 0;
    data = "Some input text";
}
public Rows(int number, String data, @NotNull Table table) {
    this.number = number;
    this.data = data;
    this.numT = table.getNum();
}
public void printRows() { System.out.print(number + ": " + data + "\n"); }
@Override
public String toString() { return number + ": " + data + "\n"; }}

public class Table {
private int num;
protected ArrayList<Rows> rowsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public Table() { num = 0; }
public Table(int num) { this.num = num; }
public void setNum(int num) { this.num = num;}
public int getNum() { return num; }
public void printTables() {
    System.out.print("Name: " + num);
}
@Override
public String toString() { return String.valueOf(num);}}

public class Handler {
ArrayList<Table> listT = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Rows> listR = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
Rows rows;
Table table;
public void printT() {
    for (Table table: listT) {
        System.out.print(table.toString());
        System.out.print(table.rowsArrayList.toString());
    }
}
public void createTable() {
    int numT;
    if (console.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Write the number of the Table");
        numT = console.nextInt();

        table = new Table(numT);
        listT.add(listT.size(), table);
    }
    else System.out.print("Please input integer value!\n");
}
public void createRows() {
    int numR, numT;
    String data;
    System.out.println("Write the number of the rows");
    if (console.hasNextInt()) {
        numR = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter any data");
        data = console.next();
        System.out.println("Chose Table: ");
        printT();
        if (console.hasNextInt()) {
            numT = console.nextInt();
            rows = new Rows(numR, data, listT.get(numT - 1));
            listT.get(numT - 1).rowsArrayList.add(listT.get(numT - 1).rowsArrayList.size(), rows);
        }
        else System.out.print("Please input integer value (number of table)!\n");
    }
    else System.out.print("Please input integer value (number of rows)!\n");
}

public void sortRowsByNum() {
    // need to sort
}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to implement the Comparable interface

```
public class Rows implements Comparable {

   @Override
   public int compareTo(Rows rows){
   
     return Integer.compare(this.number, rows.getNumber());
     // this will give you an ASC order
     //If you would like DESC order flip the comparison
   }

}
```

And then in your sortRowsByNum method in the Table class you can do this

```
public void sortRowsByNum() {
    Collections.sort(rowsArrayList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is still not solved. First, the method sortRowsByNum is in the "Handler" class, and when I tried to move it to the "table" class, I ran into other errors.